# How can I count the selected items in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, selection

Outlook 2007 shows the total number of items in a folder on the status bar at the bottom.

When I select a group of e-mails the information on the status bar does not change.

How can I find out how many items are selected?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just found out that if you select **5 or more** items and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> then it shows a warning dialog which contains the number. Something like *"Are you sure you want to open **X** items?"* (the wording could be a bit different, not using English Outlook).

I can then just click "No" and they will not be opened.

Comment: This method does not seem to work in Outlook 2010.

Comment: @SauloSilva It works on Outlook 2010.

Comment: It definitely doesn't work in MS Office 365 Version 2002... when I hit enter with selected more than 5 emails, it opens 2 of them.........

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Count Selected Items Macro](http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/countselected.htm)  That website has all the information you need to count the number of selected items in Outlook 2007.

### **Quick Install**

1. Download [this code-file](http://www.howto-outlook.com/files/countselected.zip) (countselected.zip) or copy the code below.
2. Open the VBA Editor (keyboard shortcut ALT+F11)
3. Extract the zip-file and import the `CountSelected.bas` file via File-> Import…
   If you copied the code, paste it into a new module.
4. [Add a button](http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/macrobutton.htm) for easy access to the macro.
5. [Sign your code](http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/selfcert.htm).

### Macro code

The following code is contained in the zip-file referenced in the Quick
Install. You can use the code below for review or manual installation.

```
Sub CountSelectedItems()
    Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
    Dim Result As Integer
    Set objSelection = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    Result = MsgBox("Number of selected items: " & _
      objSelection.Count, vbInformation, "Selected Items")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the best you can do is create a temporary folder, move the selected emails into that folder, and see what the count is.

Then move them back again.

Comment: That's what I tried first but it involves a lot of waiting (copying) if the number of items is high and you need the information often :)

Answer (score 2):

If all the items in the folder happen to be read, just mark the selected items as unread: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>. The number of unread items will usually be shown next to the folder name. Afterwards mark the selected items as read again: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.